# Setting column values as column names in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please I need to create an SQL query to do the following. I have two tables : "Informations" and "Disponibilities"

Table 1 ==> "Informations" :

```
email             |       Name      |      
email1@gmail.com         Name 1           
email2@gmail.com         Name 2
```

Table 2 ==> "Disponibilities" :

```
email             |       Day      |  Hour_start  |  Hour_finish  
email1@gmail.com         Monday          14h            18h
email1@gmail.com         Tuesday         16h            17h 
email1@gmail.com         Wednesday       12h            20h
email1@gmail.com         Thursday        08h            10h
email1@gmail.com         Friday          18h            19h

email2@gmail.com         Monday          10h            13h
email1@gmail.com         Tuesday         15h            17h 
email1@gmail.com         Wednesday       16h            19h
email1@gmail.com         Thursday        18h            10h
email1@gmail.com         Friday          17h            19h

...
```

I need as a result a table like this :

```
email             |  Name  |   Day    | Hr_start | Hr_finish |   Day   | Hr_start | Hr_finish | ...
email1@gmail.com    Name 1   Monday      14h        18h       Tuesday      16h       17h
email2@gmail.com    Name 2   Monday      10h        13h       Tuesday      16h       17h                 15h       17h
```

Is there any possibility to do this using a query ?

Please help me because I really have no idea about how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google:  "MySQL dynamic pivot"

Comment: i have done other way if u want i will give you u code. which display 4 rows.
  
o/p contains col:
email,Name,HOURS_TYPE,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday